# Styling the html with style tags in Amazon SES templates

Tags: amazon-ses

I am trying to style the content of my email html template on Amazon SES, by including a style tag. But it is not rendered when I receive the email.

Please let me know how can I apply styles to my email and also include images in my email using Amazon ses.
Thanks in advance

Comment: I have the same problem.  Did you find the solution?

Comment: I found that some of the css won't be applied to the email, so I googled for some sample html emails and sent them using Amazon SES. It worked for me.

Comment: I'll make this note, as I did one inline in the console the editor goofed up some of my formatting; if I had any `<!-- something -->` it may end with a `-- >` breaking its syntax.  Wasn't super apparent until I copied it back out and put it in VSCode or another editor that could highlight syntax issues.

Answer (score 5):

Try this,
set the below part to Html field.

```
 <html><head><style> .cl{ color:blue;background-color:yellow}</style></head><body><button class='cl'>hello</button></body></html>
```

When you send this you will get the button with blue text and background with yellow as shown below [image]

Hope this helps!!

Note: don't miss the head tag